# using a do loop on a range.find method keeps looping over the same cells

Tags: vba, excel, loops

i hope this is something you can help me with. i am trying to use a loop to dynamically go over 2 different ranges and look for instances of repeat values.

here is my code for the loop:

```
'my code first looks into a range and finds if a cell already exists then assigns that cell row to RowFound (there can be multiple matches of the same value)

RowFound = Find_Row(MatchVal, ColRangeA)
MatchVal = "ABC"
Do Until RowFound = 0
    'i want to loop until all rows of 'ABC' have been found so i can do the comparison in the below if statement and apply other code once found
    If MatchVal = .Cells(RowFound, ColRangeA) or MatchVal = .Cells(RowFound, ColRangeB) then 'do something
    RowFound = Find_Row(MatchVal, ColRangeA, RowFound)
Loop
```

Here is the code for my Find_Row function:

```
Function Find_Row(VAL as String, RNGCOL as Integer, Optional ByVal VALROW as Long) as Long
    Dim ValCell as Range

    Find_Row = 0
    If VALROW = 0 Then VALROW = 1

    With Thisworkbook.Sheets(1)
        Set ValCell = .Columns(RNGCOL).Find(What:=VAL, _
                        After:=.Cells(VALROW, RNGCOL), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart)

        If Not ValCell Is Nothing Then Find_Row = ValCell.Row

    End with    
End Sub
```

What ends up happening here is that I keep looping over the range! So let's say my range looks like this:

1. DDD
2. DFG
3. ABC
4. EKG
5. ABC

My loop will correctly return row 3 and then row 5. However, it will continue looping as it will just go back to 3 on the next call, etc.

What am I doing wrong? If I am using After, I would expect it to stop at the end of my range?

Comment: See example code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) you need to test for original find.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, already checked the typical documentation. the issue is that at the end of the range for some reason it keeps going back to the top even though I set the after cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott's reference is the correct one for you. In the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) it says "When the search reaches the end of the specified search range, it wraps around to the beginning of the range."

Below is one method, using your code, to capture when FIND wraps.

```
FirstRowFound = 0
RowFound = Find_Row(MatchVal, ColRangeA)
MatchVal = "ABC"
Do Until RowFound = 0
    'i want to loop until all rows of 'ABC' have been found so i can do the comparison in the below if statement and apply other code once found
    If MatchVal = Sheets(1).Cells(RowFound, ColRangeA) Or MatchVal = Sheets(1).Cells(RowFound, ColRangeB) Then 'do something
        Debug.Print "Found at " & RowFound
    End If
    RowFound = Find_Row(MatchVal, ColRangeA, RowFound)
    If FirstRowFound = 0 Then
        FirstRowFound = RowFound
    Else
        If RowFound = FirstRowFound Then RowFound = 0
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: thank you very helpful! i missed it when i glanced at the documentation. i'll update my code to test for the first row in the range to stop the wrapping around.